# Xcode binary not including images

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having a problem, have searched, and cannot figure this out. I added some new PNG images to an app and everything is working properly in the Simulator, however after I archive and run on a device, none of the new images are included.

I've checked the targets, paths, and everything seems fine but they are not included in the archived file. I've tried cleaning it and re-archiving many times but the results are the same. What could I be missing?

Comment: How did deducted that the images are not in the achieved version? Did you op de IPA (just a zip file.)? Also be aware that the simulator is often not case sensitive where the device is, so `image.png` does not equal `Image.png`

Comment: I archived, saved as an IPA and installed on my device. There are no issues with case sensitivity. Basically this app is a sticker type app and I added another new pack of stickers. The filename format is the same as the other packs.

Comment: Open the IPA and verify that the files are there.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you delete the app from the simulator, clean your project and launch it again? Simulator has some kind of cache

Comment: are the images in your target? i.e. checked in inspector-> Target Membership?

Comment: deleted from simulator, cleaned, and relaunched and they are still there in the simulator. Yes the target memberships are the exact same as the other previous images that work.

Comment: Ok I am an idiot! Figured it out, it WAS a case sensitivity issue. I was looking at the file name not the extension. My other files were .PNG and these were just .png.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you name the files correctly, any typo can cause the misbehavior, e.g. capitals or non-capitals, resources should always have their extensions and so on.

Comment: Yep, iOS is case-sensitive while OSx (and the simulator) is not.